# Exception with creating Edge inside Transaction

Tags: orientdb

I'm really new to orientDB , so I'm probably doing something very wrong, still here it goes:

```
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("remote:localhost/testdb","root","12345").setupPool(2, 10);;
```

I created a few VertexTypes and EdgeTypes:

```
OrientGraphNoTx graph = factory.getNoTx();
graph.createVertexType("Company");
graph.createVertexType("Contract");
graph.createEdgeType("SignedWith");
```

Also created a few indexes :

```
graph.createKeyIndex("itemid", Vertex.class, new Parameter<>("class", "Contract" ));
graph.createKeyIndex("itemid", Vertex.class, new Parameter<>("class", "Company"));
```

Now while creating I do the following :

```
OrientGraph graph = factory.getTx();

Vertex contract = graph.addVertex("class:Contract");
contract.setProperty("itemid", field.longValue());
[... many other properties]

Vertex company = graph.addVertex("class:Company");
company.setProperty("itemid", field.longValue());
[... many other properties]

contract.addEdge("SignedWith", company);
// Also tried this way:
//graph.addEdge(null, contract, company ,"SignedWith" );
```

And everytime I keep getting :

```
[debug] c.j.n.n.OrientDBUtils - verify contract has id : #16:-2
[debug] c.j.n.n.OrientDBUtils - verify company has id : #12:-2
[error] c.j.n.c.OrientDBIndexerRunnable - NeoIndexerRunnable - indexing problem Contract Id:20
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ORecordNotFoundException: The record with id '#16:-2' not found
 at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecordAbstract.reload(ORecordAbstract.java:320) ~[orientdb-core-2.0-M3.jar:2.0-M3]
 at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.reload(ODocument.java:653) ~[orientdb-core-2.0-M3.jar:2.0-M3]
 at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.reload(ODocument.java:69) ~[orientdb-core-2.0-M3.jar:2.0-M3]
 at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecordAbstract.checkForLoading(ORecordAbstract.java:470) ~[orientdb-core-2.0-M3.jar:2.0-M3]
 at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.rawField(ODocument.java:819) ~[orientdb-core-2.0-M3.jar:2.0-M3]
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ORecordNotFoundException: Record with rid #16:-2 was not found in database
 at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.reload(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1389) ~[orientdb-core-2.0-M3.jar:2.0-M3]
 at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.reload(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:123) ~[orientdb-core-2.0-M3.jar:2.0-M3]
 at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecordAbstract.reload(ORecordAbstract.java:314) ~[orientdb-core-2.0-M3.jar:2.0-M3]
 at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.reload(ODocument.java:653) ~[orientdb-core-2.0-M3.jar:2.0-M3]
 at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.reload(ODocument.java:69) ~[orientdb-core-2.0-M3.jar:2.0-M3]
```

Am I missing something ?

Running with orientDB 2.0-M3 on Linux.

Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the transaction is rolledback between the creation of the Vertexes.

I was expecting to see a more explicit Exception when creating a Vertex with a OrientGraph object, when a transaction isn't available or was rolledback. It in fact creates a new Transaction automatically .